# Passing block into a method -  Ruby

Tags: ruby, block

I have a little question on passing block.

```
def a_method(a, b)
  a + yield(a, b)
end
```

This works fine.

```
k = a_method(1, 2) do |x, y| 
  (x + y) * 3 
end
puts k
```

But this won't work.

```
puts a_method(1, 2) do |x, y| 
  (x + y) * 3 
end
# LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
```

Can anyone kindly explain this to me?

Thanks. Example taken from Metaprogramming Ruby by Paolo Perrotta. Great book.

Comment: See also: [Ruby Block Syntax Error](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6854283/), [Code block passed to `each` works with brackets but not with `do`-`end` (ruby)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6718340/), [Block definition - difference between braces and `do`-`end` ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6179442/), [Ruby multiline block without `do` `end`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3680097/), [Using `do` block vs brackets `{}`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2122380/), [What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/533008/), …

Comment: … [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/420147/), [Why aren't `do`/`end` and `{}` always equivalent?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7487664/) and [Wierd imperfection in Ruby blocks](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7620804/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `do .. end` and curly braces is that the **curly braces bind to the rightmost** expression, while **`do .. end` bind to the leftmost** one. Observe the following examples:

```
def first(x=nil)
  puts "  first(#{x.inspect}): #{block_given? ? "GOT BLOCK" : "no block"}"
  "f"
end

def second(x=nil)
  puts "    second(#{x.inspect}): #{block_given? ? "GOT BLOCK" : "no block"}"
  "s"
end

first second do |x| :ok end #   second(nil): no block
                            # first("s"): GOT BLOCK

first second {|x| :ok }     #   second(nil): GOT BLOCK
                            # first("s"): no block
```

In the first case, the block made with `do..end` will be bound to the first function (leftmost). In the second case the block made with curly brackets will be bound to the second function (rightmost).

Usually it's good idea to use parentheses if you have two functions and a block - just for readability and to avoid mistakes.

It's very easy to accidentally pass a block to `puts` method, just as in your question.

Answer (score -1):

That's because the block is passed to `puts` and not to `a_method`.
This should do it:

```
puts (a_method(1, 2) { |x, y| (x + y) * 3 })

# if you want to keep it multilines
puts (a_method(1, 2) { |x, y|
  (x + y) * 3
})
```

Comment: Hi, can you give me an example with the do..end? I did try with the curly brackets before that. Was trying to figure out how to use the do..end.

Comment: I kept searching but found nothing about this issue. Maybe `puts` isn't simply supposed to have a do...end inside it (that makes sense because it's not supposed to display multiline stuff)? You can still keep using braces even for a multiline block.